# Running applications on an old Java versions

Tags: java, security

What are the risks associated with running an application on an older (most likely unsupported Java version)

Suppose I have a desktop application that requires Java 6 installed and pointed to. While I understand the risks associated with running applications exposed to internet connection (via browser plug-in for example), I am not sure it is clear how old versions of Java can pose risks to applications and environments not exposed to external networks (if at all)?

Comment: Why would a desktop application require Java 6? What part would break backwards compatibility if you were to run it on, let's say Java 8?

Comment: This is one of the prerequisites for running it, if I launch it with Java 8 installed alone I receive an error message

Comment: Why? Java is backwards compatible. That's not a realistic prerequisite.

Comment: @Kayaman. There are cases that it is not. Also, if implementation of business logic is wrong, it my cause other issues (changed hash algorithm for example)

Comment: If you have code written by incompetent people breaking the backwards compatibility, then it's more likely that there are more attack vectors resulting from their code, rather than from the Java environment itself.

Comment: @Kayaman Ok, I will give you another example: java.sql.Driver, method with name: getParentLogger() is added since 1.7. What happen if you implement it and change from 1.6 to 1.8

Comment: If it's public, then congratulations, you've implemented a method which is in the interface. If you're writing your own JDBC drivers, I'd expect you to be experienced enough to support drivers on different JDBC / JRE levels where necessary. See for example [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/postgresql/postgresql). Of course JDBC drivers are quite special as well.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure it is clear how old versions of Java can pose risks to applications and environments not exposed to external networks (if at all)?

If the old JVM isn't used at all, then it *probably*<sup>1</sup> presents no risk ... until it is used by accident, etc.

If a Java application on an old JVM doesn't use networking at all, then there is *probably*<sup>1</sup> no overt risk<sup>2</sup> of using an old JVM.

If the application uses networks on your organization's internal networks, then there are risks:

- Your organizations firewalls may not be as secure as you think.
- There are various ways that someone could get onto your internal networks; e.g. via a (different) trojan horse application, etcetera.  Once in, they could launch attacks against your internal servers.
- Don't discount the possibility of a rogue employee.

---

You stated as a reason for not upgrading:

> This is one of the prerequisites for running it, if I launch it with Java 8 installed alone I receive an error message.

That means you are using an out-of-date or out-of-maintenance application.  That is a risk in of itself.

Upgrade the application to a Java 8 compatible version, or transition to an alternative for the application that will run on Java 8 and will be supported<sup>3</sup> into the future.  (And next time, pay more attention to upgrades / support / longevity of the applications that your / your organization invest in!)

---

<sup>1 - But nobody can be entirely certain of that.</sup>

<sup>2 - But there is a latent risk, in that if there are previously undisclosed security issues in the old JVM that could be exploited, then they won't get patched.</sup>

<sup>3 - Or choose an open source application that you will be able to support yourself ... if necessary.</sup>

Comment: Unfortunatelly that happens mainly by newbie/part time developers who do not care about distribution. Even I've seen app installers poiting the user-wide JAVA_HOME to its own JRE copy which is terrifying :/

Answer (score 1):

If an application is very dependent on the version of JRE, it is recommended that the application is bundled with the required JRE. (it is valid for any runtime, not only Java), so you may have a copy of the JRE6 dedicated to your app

> I am not sure it is clear how old versions of Java can pose risks to applications and environments

the biggest issue IMHO is if you use an obsolete JRE as a system-registered runtime, so it will be used for running any jar file or java-based apps without the user knowing it is used. Since JRE7 and 8 there were many security and performance issues fixed and a lot of features added.

So - if you really must use Java 6, do not *install* it, just copy the JRE (that is allowed by the distribution license).

you may point to the JRE inside the scripts of the application. Under no circumstances you should use system/user wide env variables (JAVA_HOME) to point to the obsolete JRE.